# Как скачать в папку на пк фото из Telegram бота?(Python)

Tags: python-3.x, изображения

Пишу бота с использованием библиотеки pyTelegramBotAPI. Есть задача скачать фото без сжатия(как я понимаю вариант в логе номер 3). Как это сделать в питоне 3?
Такой код не работает:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
        def Zagruzka_informazii(massage):
            file_info = bot.get_file(massage.photo[len(massage.photo) - 1].file_id)

            downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
            src = 'C:\Bot\ ' + file_info.file_path;
            with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
                new_file.write(downloaded_file)
            bot.reply_to(massage, "Фото добавлено")
```

Ошибка:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Bot\\ photos/file_0.jpg'
```